# HTML5 video freezes on IE10 when controlling it through video player

Tags: javascript, html, video, internet-explorer-10

I have observed a strange problem on my HTML5 web application on IE 10 windows 7. The problem occurs when sliding the thumb of the video player, or clicking +30s or -30s numerous times the browser freezes and after sometime the message box to **"recover page"** comes.

Comment: are you adding any events triggered by the video that might be stacking up? have you had a look in the developer tools (or networking) console to see if there are any errors showing up?

Comment: I don't think it is happening because of any event stacking or any other script error. Even I am experiencing the same issue on following link.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video
Whenever I try to play with the controls (Especially with slider thumb and +30s or -30s) of the video player vigorously, the browser just hangs up and CPU usage shoots up.